Debian 12 rebooting/crashing almost randomly
this is my first time really getting into Linux. It's been somewhat smooth, but when I try to use applications, after some time my laptop's screen will go black and after a couple seconds it will go back to the boot screen like I had just turned it back on. I'm not exactly sure what is causing this, but I think it might have to do with my graphics hardware. I tried stress testing with glmark2 and it replicates exactly what previously happens immediately. Any help would be appreciated.
My Laptop is a framework 16 ryzen 9, running debain 12.

Hello, from what I understand it could be an issue with the ram or motherboard, can you check if they have physical damage, also try go on the bios to run some hardware test

@Maslie I’m looking at the internals right now, but I’m not seeing anything that looks damaged or broken. Also I’ve looked through the bios and I didn’t see any kind of hardware test.

Check the power, make sure you don't have small cut on it that could force the pc to reboot.

I checked the manufacturer’s website and apparently the laptop isn’t compatible with Debian. I installed fedora and now it’s working. Thanks for your help.

You could post the link of your finding in your answer for more clarity

Framework 16 isn’t compatible with Debian. Use fedora or smt.
